# Send GPS coordinates via VHF

Tags: radio, gps

I want to set up a system such that wherever a user of VHF presses the PTT button the coordinates from a GPS receiver will transmited to receiver and stored in a computer. Is that possible ?  Where should I look around for something like that?

Comment: If you get an amateur radio license, you could use a 2 meter band radio with APRS and GPS. For example, the Yaesu VX-8R is about $400 and would just about do exactly what you're asking for. I don't know what the requirements for a license are where you live, but it's pretty easy over here.

Comment: I got any licence needed. I dont have only the know how to do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For transmitting data across a VHF or similar radio link you're going to either need a radio modem or to build one yourself to convert the data bits into tones that can be passed across the link.

While you could, in theory, use an modem device designed for telephone line use (minus the telephone line interface circuitry), a device designed specifically for radio use such as the [CMX469A](http://www.cmlmicro.com/Products/index.asp?/Products/WData/CMX469A.htm&searchvalue=wd&setindex=1) (from [CML Microcircuits](http://www.cmlmicro.com/)) would be a much better device, this [application note](http://www.cmlmicro.com/Products/applications/AN_WDATA_469AFW_1.pdf) should provide the basis for the system you've described.

Answer (score 6):

## FOR LICENSED HAM RADIO AMATEURS ONLY!!

This is what Theran says:

APRS is the solution.

There are several sites to track your APRS position.

1. aprs.fi
2. openaprs.net
3. ...

Frequencies can be found on the [APRS wiki](http://info.aprs.net/index.php?title=Frequencies).

Low budged APRS transmitters
A [Tinytrack](http://www.byonics.com/tinytrak/) is a Terminal Node Controller (TNC) you can couple to almost any modern VHF car transceiver.

Or a microtrack with buld in tinytrack 3 chip.

See the [byonics](http://www.byonics.com/) web site.

Comment: What is Theran ?

Comment: @rocketmagnet, I think it's me :)